# Sliding the Panel

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, panel, move

I'm using WinForms. In My form i have a button and a panel. When i click on that button i want to slide the panel to the right. I'm having issues with the code. Currently I'm getting red error lines under
`= panel2.Location.X + 1;`

`Error Message: Cannot implicitly convert type int to System.Drawing.Point`

I was trying to move the panel with the similar approach i did by growing the panel. I provided that in my code. How can i move the panel?

```
private void btn_Right_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
    // Make Panel Grow
    //while (panel1.Width < 690)
    //{
    //    panel1.Width = panel1.Width + 1;
    //}

    while (panel2.Location.X < 690)
    {
        panel2.Location = panel2.Location.X + 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: well what do the errors in red say..? we are not mind readers here..

Comment: you are trying to assign int to a Point

Comment: sorry, Error: Cannot implicitly convert type int to System.Drawing.Point @MethodMan

Comment: why not do something like the following 
`panel2.Location = new Point(x,y);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get an error because you try to set the location with an integer. You will need a new point instance:

```
panel2.Location = new Point(panel2.Location.X, panel2.Location.Y + 1);
```

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick. I'm going to look up new point instances. Still learning these terms :) @c.wider

Comment: is there a way to write the code like this  panel2.Location = new Point(panel2.Location.X +0.5, panel2.Location.Y); .....(0.5 )so the slide will be slower. Instead of  + 1

Comment: no, a location of a control can only be presented by an integer, but I think your problem is not a too fast sliding than a refreshing problem. Try to Refresh the control after every set of the location like this: panel2.Refresh()

Answer (score 0):

Try using .Left instead of .Location.X

This works in VB...

```
Private Sub Button6_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button6.Click
    If sender.text = ">" Then
        Do Until Panel1.Left > Me.Width - 50
            Panel1.Left += 1
        Loop
        sender.text = "<"
    Else
        Panel1.Left = 511
        sender.text = ">"
    End If
End Sub
```

I'm surprised it is a smooth as it is - panel is empty however.